# Replace everything after specific character in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, cell

So I have a document with 30k+ emails. The probleme is, during the export random characters appeared after the emails, something like name@email.com2019-10-10T0545152019-10-10T054515f or name@email.com00000000000700392019-11-28T070033f

My question is, how do i remove everything after ".com" or ".fr" in all the cells ?

Comment: I use google-sheets. I tried the search and replace as i don't know how to enter a function to all the cells. I'm new do google sheets

Comment: You have currently some nice answers at your disposal. However, I have voted to close your question since it's currently off-topic. You can refer to [ask] a question with an [mcve]. It's most appreciated to include your own attempt. Using GS it may also be wise to share a copy of your workbook.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using REGEXREPLACE.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\.com.*|\.fr.*", "")
```

Comment: A headsup norie. You are currently removing everything ***including*** ".com" or ".fr". You may want to use: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\.(com|fr).*",".$1")` =)

Comment: Is there a way to apply this function to all the cells ?

Comment: I just tried that and it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".+\.com|.+\.fr")
```

Comment: Hi Tom, nice alternative. A FYI, you can avoid backtracking using a non-capture group. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/8vGDkI/1) example using 1357 steps vs. [this](https://regex101.com/r/898T5W/1) taking only 47 steps. Imagine this difference in what is most likely going to be an arrayformula for OP =)

Answer (score 1):

Working from what other people added, you can get all emails from the column A and use regular expressions to get the values. Using `ARRAYFORMULA` you can do it in a single formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>""; REGEXEXTRACT(A:A; ".+\.(?:com|fr)"); ""))
```

### Rundown

- `ARRAYFORMULA` allows to execute the formula to the entire column
- `REGEXEXTRACT` extracts part of the string using regular expressions
- `IF` conditional. In this case it's used to no execute when the cell is empty, preventing an error.

### References

- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [REGEXEXTRACT (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [IF (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Comment: It says error when i try that. I really don't know what to do, I don't even know if i'm writing the formula in the right place and if all the cells are selected

Comment: Hi @ColinThanasi. Your locale (french?) may require the use of semi-colons in formulas. So try replacing the commas with semi colons (;) and see if it then works?

Comment: Are you adding it on another column on row 1?

Comment: @JPV True. Didn't think about that

Comment: @ColinThanasi And what does it say if you hover the mouse over it?

Comment: @Marti It says "Circular dependency detected. To resolve the issue with an iterative calculation, go to File> Worksheet Settings." Sorry for the bad translation it's in french

Comment: Don't add it in Column A. If it's in another sheet, remember to add `Sheet1!` (or the actual sheet name) before the `A:A`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your raw-data email list were in A2:A, try this in, Row 2 of an otherwise empty column (e.g., B2):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^.+\.\D+")))`

In plain English, this means "Extract everything up to the last dot found that is followed by some number of non-digits."

This should pull up to any suffix (e.g., **.com**, **.co**, **.biz**, **.org**, **.ma.gov**, etc.).